# Aggregating Qualtrics responses within user

Tags: qualtrics

I have a classification task that I'm seeking to do via Qualtrics. Essentially, each participant sees a randomly generated piece of embedded data (from a total of 400 embedded data fields), and answers 5 questions about this piece of data. Each participant does this 10 times (i.e. they classify 10 pieces of data). Each classification task comprises of the same five muliple-choice questions. Is there any way to aggregate the answers obtained to each question and see the aggregate results? For instance, the first question in each task is "was this written before or after purchase?", and I want to see 10 yes/no answers together for each participant, and also aggregated across participants (right now Qualtrics aggregates them only across participants, but not within).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Qualtrics scoring functionality to aggregate within participants: https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-tools/response-management-tools/scoring/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this just now, but it gives me a composite score at the end of the survey, whereas I want them aggregated by question (e.g. for each participant I want Question 1.1, 2.1...10.1 together, Question 1.2, 2.2...10.2 together, and so on)...

Comment: Setup different scoring categories for each group of questions you want to aggregate.  Then you'll have a score for each group.

Comment: Great, glad it worked out.  Please accept the answer.